# Почему не открывается страница openServer при XDebug?

Tags: php, phpstorm, openserver, xdebug

установил xdebug в phpstorm,и через openServer хочу сделать отладку,сначала всё нормально работало,но я нажал на какую кнопку.отладка исчезла,а страница в браузере вообще не открывается(Не удается получить доступ к сайту),другие проекты в openserver открываются и всё работает,кроме того где установлен xdebug

Comment: это так забавно читать...... я что-то нажал и всё упало.....и что же вы от нас хотите? мы не ясновидящие.......уж если вы не знаете, то мы и подавно.......... "*всё работает,кроме того где установлен xdebug*" --- это вообще какая-то неадекватная фраза..... xdebug  устанавливается на конкретную версию php, т.е. работает **со всеми проектами** и распространяется на них все. Установить xdebug на конкреный проект невозможно в принципе

Comment: Перезагружайте комп, глядишь повезёт..... а скорее проблема просто в коде где-нибудь. 500 ошибка